# Access Apache 2.4's localhost from another system in same network

Tags: django, apache, networking, server, private-network

I am running a Django application on Apache2.4 server. I wish to access the page http://localhost:8081/home from another system. I'm in a corporate environment so both server and client machine will be inside a same private network.

So the issue is, I am being able to access the page by using the server IP address, on the server machine (http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081/home ) but the page is not being loaded when I use it on the client machine. ( similarly, I can access the page as systemname.dns.com:8081/home from server machine but not from client machine)

So what can exactly be my problem and how can I solve it?

Modified part of httpd.conf:

```
LoadFile c:/users/username/appdata/local/programs/python/python36/python36.dll
LoadModule wsgi_module
c:/users/username/lms/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
WSGIScriptAlias / c:/users/username/lms/LMS/wsgi.py WSGIPythonHome c:/users/username/lms WSGIPythonPath c:/users/username/lms

<Directory "C:/Users/username/lms">
     <Files wsgi.py>
         Require all granted
     </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: show VirtualHost tag completly

Comment: I didnt add the virtualhost tag. Is it mandatory? If yes, can you explain the process stepwise? @Vermus

Comment: please read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Comment: If you didn't have ``VirtualHost`` in the Apache configuration (rather than not in your question), then it should listen on all interfaces. In that case, it is likely you have a firewall setup on the server which blocks inbound requests on the port being used.

Comment: But I have added an inbound rule for that particular port in my firewall settings. Still, doesn't seem to be working.